# Why does Ubuntu need two kernels?

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel

My computer has rather low disk space. For this reason every so often I need to run `sudo apt autoremove` to remove old kernels and headers and stuff.

Not that long ago, I noticed that it has kept 4.4.0.77 as well as 4.4.0.78. I have run autoremove twice since noticing, but it still is there. I only use the latest kernel, and I don't think any of my software depends on that particular version, but when I tried to remove it, it wanted to remove `linux-image-generic`. That sounds important, so I didn't, but why does it depend on an outdated kernel version?

Comment: I highly doubt that `linux-image-generic` depended on the *second* most recent kernel image version on your system. Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `dpkg-query -l linux-image-\* | grep ^ii`? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I have allready specified why I think `linux-image-generic` depends on it.

Comment: I don't see an explanation as to *why* you believe it is that way, just a statement *that* you do. I'd also like to confirm that you're not mistaken since this situation is pretty hard to believe and would require further investigation anyway. The output of `dpkg-query -Wf '${Status;1} ${Package}\n' linux-image-\* | sed -ne 's/^i //p' | xargs apt-cache policy` would be even better suited to that.

Comment: @DavidFoerster `but when I tried to remove it, it wanted to remove linux-image-generic.`

Comment: Oh, it seems we meant different levels of explanation. I'd consider that an observation, not an explanation. There are other plausible explanations for this observation am I'm asking for more information to look into them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ubuntu does not need two kernels. It keeps one "backup" kernel in case you can't boot with the latest one.

You can safely remove the older kernel if you are sure you won't need it.

And you probably tried to remove the latest one if `linux-image-generic` was  to be removed. It depends on the latest kernel only.

Comment: As long as the other packages (`linux-image-generic`, `linux-cloud-tools`, etc.) have the exact same version number, this is fine.  They generally should, if the `apt-get remove` command was well enough specified.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu keeps all the previous kernels by defaults. You can safely remove them by issuing `sudo apt autoremove` without any arguments. It will then show you the list of "cached" packages and ask if you want to remove them. You do.

Comment: Maybe you mean `sudo apt-get autoremove`?

Comment: @GeppettvsD'Constanzo nope :) apt (it's been a while now) is now an alias to most apt-* functions ; try it!

Comment: Your command is returning `E: Invalid operation autoremove` in a terminal. I am using 14.04 LTS. So I guess I don't have such alias in my system. Maybe in newer versions? Thank you!